# PHP - reload new record upon page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, post

I have a little problem with my PHP code and database. Every time i refresh the page, a new empty row is being added to the database also when i open the page, what is the problem?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","dwarfmaster","");

    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("my_dwarfmaster", $con);

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $release_year = $_POST['release_year'];
    $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO gamelist (name, release_year, publisher, genre)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[release_year]',
        '$_POST[publisher]','$_POST[genre]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and say that you have your form in the same page. Use `isset()` against a (named) submit button.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Check `isset` and `empty` the `$_POST`

Comment: $_POST is always going to be set.  If no data was posted, it will just be an empty array.  As Bora suggested, you will need to check if empty()

Comment: $_POST always exists, it's just empty if no data is posted.  Use !empty () instead of isset ().  By the way, your code is WIDE OPEN to SQL injection attacks.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I meant to add `if(empty())` which is (also) what needs to be done. Plus as John noted. You have more than enough information to get things done (right). Plus, being nested inside inside an `if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){...}` for the submit button, to prevent from being accidentally submitted. A header could be used also to redirect to another page.

Comment: You can create a hidden fields and put a value in that..then use if(isset($_POST['your hidden field name']))

Comment: Quick sidenote: if you refresh this page after submitting, the POST data is submitted again and it will insert new rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or simply change

```
if (isset($_POST))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if the request method is post, use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

`if(isset($_POST))` will always return true

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code-:

> if( !empty(array_filter($_POST)) ) { . . Code to insert data into data base
>   from form . .  }

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isset($_POST))
```

will always return true !

try

```
    if (isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['release_year'])
             &&isset($_POST['publisher'])&&isset($_POST['genre']))
```

instead to check each time for each and every variable !